# How to pass custom attribute to a styled component in a functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, styled-components

I'm trying to understand how this thing works, but all examples that I found was written in a class fashion.

```
   import React from 'react'
   import styled from 'styled-components/native'

   const MyTag = styled.Button.attrs({
     title: myThisThingValue
   })`
     // some style
     background: thisIsAlsoMyThingValue
   \` 

   export default function MyComponent({ props }) {
     return(
       <MyTag myThisThing="My value" thisIsAlsoMyThing="Other Value" />
         )
   }
```

I'm just want access to my custom attributes in the MyTag styled. I used a `(props) => {title: props.MyThing }` in .attrs() but didn't work.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You'll make functions for the individual attributes, not for the entire attrs parameter. For example:

```
   const MyTag = styled.Button.attrs({
     title: (props) => props.myThisThing
   })`
     background: ${props => props.thisIsAlsoMyThing}
   `
```

Answer (score 27):

that should work:

**JavaScript Version:**

```
export const MyTag = styled.button.attrs(props => ({
  title: props.myThisThingValue,
}))`
  background: ${props => props.thisIsAlsoMyThing};
`;
```

**TypeScript Version:**

```
interface MyTagProps {
  myThisThingValue: string;
  thisIsAlsoMyThing: string;
}

export const MyTag = styled.button.attrs((props: MyTagProps) => ({
  title: props.myThisThingValue,
}))<MyTagProps>`
  background: ${props => props.thisIsAlsoMyThing};
`;
```

**Use it:**

```
<MyTag myThisThingValue="My value" thisIsAlsoMyThing="red" />
```

Answer (score 4):

In this case `title` is a `defined attribute`, but if you need a data attribute like `indexNumber` (not defined attribute) you will need to use the prefix `data-*`:

```
export const TagName = styled.button.attrs((props) => {
  return {
    data-indexNumber: "indexNumber value"
  };
})``;
```

[Using data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Answer (score -2):

you could use something like that

```
interface Props {
  disabled?: boolean;
}

interface Attrs {
  href?: string;
}

const Link = styled.a.attrs(({ href = "#" }: Attrs) => ({
  href,
  onClickCapture: (event: any) => event.preventDefault()
}))`
  color: ${({ disabled = false }: Props) => (disabled ? "#eee" : "initial")};
`;
```

and then use it

```
<Link href="http://google.com" target={"_blank"}>
   Click here
</Link>
```

I've got some issue with a different version of styled-component tho' :/